# unselect items in Ranger (file manager)

Tags: selection, ranger

I am using the Ranger file manager, and I like it quite a lot. I often use the :mark command to select specific items in the current folder. And now comes the problem: Once I am done doing whatever I wanted with them, I don't know how to unselect the items again in a batch. So I usually :mark one specific file and then press Space to clear the selection. Sometimes I return to a folder days after still finding certain items still marked/highlighted/selected.
I couldn't find an "unselect_all" command yet. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<kbd>uv</kbd> is the default shortcut. From rc.conf:

`map uv      mark_files all=True val=False`

Answer (score 10):

`unmark` might be the command you should have guessed yourself :)

Comment: This only unmarks marked files in the current directory. When I mark files over several directories then try `unmark`, the files in other directories remain marked.